# Why am I getting an "unknown escape character" error for this code

Tags: c++

This code is throwing the error

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040' [enabled by default]
```

`std::cout << "\nPlease choose a race:\n"
                    "1. Elf\ n"
                    "2. Human\n"
                    "3. Vampire\n"
                    "4. Druid\n"
                    "5. Troll\n"
                    "6. Orc\n"
                    "7. Dwarf\n"
                    "8. Race Info\n" ;`

No idea why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the literal `"\ n"` is not a valid escape sequence. `040` represents a space in what I'm assuming is octal. You need to change 1. to `"\n"`

Comment: Oh my god. I feel extremely stupid, thanks. I knew \040 was a space.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alice Please accept and upvote if this solved your problem.

Comment: Weird, it was throwing the error on number 8 and I was so confued. I will do, thanks!